# Regex replacement line by line in Python 3

Tags: python, regex, svg, replace, inline

I have written some code to try and do the following

- Open SVG file I have already retrieved earlier in the Python code
- Look through the file for a particular regex (r"(?:xlink:href\=\")(.*)(?:\?q=80\"/>)")
- If the match is found, replace the text with a particular string e.g.
  https://regex101.com/r/IECsHu/1
- Then retrieve the JPG from the url which is matched (see above link to regex101.com)

However, this does not work and completely blanks the file out (so it is 0 bytes)

I think I must be very close to getting this working, but haven't managed it yet. Any guidance would be appreciated

```
pagenumber=1
directory_in_str='/home/somewhere/somedir/'
pathlist = Path(directory_in_str).glob('**/*.svg')
for path in pathlist:
#because path is object not string
  path_in_str = str(path)   
  print(path_in_str)

  with open(path_in_str, 'r+') as f:
    for line in f:
        myregex = r"(?:xlink:href\=\")(.*)(?:\?q=80\"\/\>)"
        result = myregex.search(line)

        if result:
            #If a match is found, replace the text in the line          
            origfullimgfilename = result
            formattedpagenumber = '{:0>3}'.format(pagenumber)
            replfullimgfilename='page-'+str(formattedpagenumber)+'-img1.jpg'
            line = re.sub(origfullimgfilename, replfullimgfilename, line.rstrip())  
            #Then retrieve the file! (origfullimgfilename)
            try:
                urllib.request.urlretrieve(origfullimgfilename+"?q=100", replfullimgfilename)
            except urllib.error.HTTPError as e:
                print("HTTP Error: "+str(e.code)+" - SVG URL: "+str(origfullimgfilename)+" - aborting\n")
                break
pagenumber += 1
```

Comment: It should not happen. Posting whole program and input file would help others checking on it.

Comment: Hi @ben Which part should not happen?  The code above runs as a standalone, once the SVG files are in the directory.... I've separated it into a separate .py file as everything to this point works fine.

Comment: check what is `result`, with a modified version of the code I have : `<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(73, 305), match='xlink:href="https://cdn-assets.somewhere.com/f929>`... It should not be: `myregex = re.compile("(?:xlink:href\=\")(.*)(?:\?q=80\"\/\>)")`?

Comment: @xdze2 it should be 'https://cdn-assets.somewhere.com/f929e7b4404d3e48918cdc0ecd4efbc9fa91dab5_2734/9c237c7e35efe88878f9e5f7a3555f7a379ed9ee9d95b491b6d0003fd80afc6b/9c68a28d6b5161f7e975a163ff093a81172916e23c778068c6bfefcfab195154.jpg'

Answer (score 0):

```
lines = """<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<!-- Page 1 -->
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0" y="0" width="1198" height="1576" viewBox="0 0 1198 1576" version="1.1" style="display: block;margin-left: auto;margin-right: auto;">
<path d="M0,0 L0,1576 L1198,1576 L1198,0 Z " fill="#FFFFFF" stroke="none"/>
<image preserveAspectRatio="none" x="0" y="0" width="1199" height="1577" xlink:href="https://cdn-assets.somewhere.com/f929e7b4404d3e48918cdc0ecd4efbc9fa91dab5_2734/9c237c7e35efe88878f9e5f7a3555f7a379ed9ee9d95b491b6d0003fd80afc6b/9c68a28d6b5161f7e975a163ff093a81172916e23c778068c6bfefcfab195154.jpg?q=80"/>
<g fill="#112449">
<use xlink:href="#f0_2" transform="matrix(19.1,0,0,19.1,885.3,204.3)"/>
<use xlink:href="#f0_o" transform="matrix(19.1,0,0,19.1,910,204.3)"/>
<use xlink:href="#f0_t" transform="matrix(19.1,0,0,19.1,930.3,204.3)"/>
<use xlink:href="#f0_f" transform="matrix(19.1,0,0,19.1,949.6,204.3)"/>"""

import re

newlines = []
for line in lines.split('\n'):
    myregex = re.compile(r"(?:xlink:href\=\")(.*)(?:\?q=80\"\/\>)")
    result = myregex.search(line)

    if result:
        print(result)
        #If a match is found, replace the text in the line          
        origfullimgfilename = result.group(1)
        replfullimgfilename='page-##-img1.jpg'
        line = re.sub(origfullimgfilename, replfullimgfilename, line)  

    newlines.append(line)

print( '\n'.join(newlines) )
```

Comment: That looks like it will work, but I want to do it 'in place' within an svg file... that code does it print out the whole file whether the line is matched or not?

Comment: the only solution I found is to loop over `enumerate(line_list)`, and then `line_list[i] = re.sub()`... (`re.sub` returns a copy of the string), Do you want to do the an in-place replacement for a performance/memory reason?

Comment: Not really, just to make it neater. Thanks though, I will try writing to a separate file that way.. thanks

Comment: OK that works, but when I change the regex to   myregex = re.compile("(?:xlink:href\=\")(.*?q=80)")
 it doesn't ...

Comment: and with `(?:xlink:href\=\")([^\"]*.jpg)`? : I added `.jpg` because it matched also `<use xlink:href="#f0_f"`... and I don't know if you want to include the `?q=` parts